# Why is Eclipse PHP not recognizing namespace declarations?

Tags: php, eclipse, namespaces

When I type "namespace ORM;" in Eclipse, it underlines ORM in red and says that it is expecting a parenthesis.  Is there a way to make Eclipse recognize namespaces?

Comment: Just attempted that, and I also tried updating to the latest version of eclipse on the site with no luck.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's probably your project that is set to the `5.1/5.2` version. You can change the default in:

`Window` > `Preferences` > `PHP` > `PHP Interpreter` > `PHP Version` > `5.3`

Alternatively you can go in `Project Properties` (right-click your project then Properties) then `PHP Interpreter`, tick `Enable project-specific settings` and change the `PHP Version` there.