# Confused about assertEquals not in phpunit anymore

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I don't see discussion forums over at phpunit.de so I'm hoping anyone using phpunit in this community can assist.

I downloaded the phpunit 6.4.3 phar and added it to my IDE.  When I tried to extend the test class with PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase and use assertEquals, it throws this error:

"PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase cannot be resolved to a type"

The IDE wants to change TestCase to PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Matcher

So I let the IDE make the correction but there isn't an assertEquals method anymore (I checked just to be sure, by changing the phar, that assertEquals is in version 5.7.23 though).

Perhaps I'm overlooking the documentation, but when I Google PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Matcher, I'm seeing what the new method is.

Does anyone know to perform an equivalent assertEquals test in version 6.4.3?

=====

EDIT.  Adding screenshots of my phpunit install, the project build path, and the  Eclipse error.

[image: install]

[image: build path]

[image: Eclipse]

Comment: I recommend removing phar file completely, both from disk and settings and follow this tutorial instead https://mike42.me/blog/2015-08-continuous-testing-in-php-with-eclipse :)

Comment: I followed the webpage.  Same results as before.  If I do this with PHPUnit 5.7 it works just fine.  If my composer.json has "phpunit/phpunit": "6.3.*" (or 6.4), it does not work.  It doesn't work because the line class ExampleTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase { throws "PHPUnit_Framework cannot be resolved to a type".

Comment: Did you set PHP to 7+ in your IDE settings like suggested here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589960/why-is-eclipse-php-not-recognizing-namespace-declarations I really want to help you solve this one :)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but I've been on travel.  Yes, PHP 7.1 is set as the version.  In fact, Eclipse resolves the version automagically when pointing to the php.exe.  Thanks for your assistance -- I really appreciate your efforts on this!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your IDE doesn't support namespaces or has some trouble with it, check your settings. It's also possible you are using PHP 5.2 or lower which doesn't support namespaces. This underscore notation was used to identify the path to a class in old-school autoloading classes.

```
<?php
namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Testing;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase as BaseTestCase;

abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase {}
```

BTW. is it a composer project? If yes, it's recommended to download/install phpunit via composer.

```
composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit ^6.4
```

Comment: I'm using Eclipse Oxygen.1 (Sep 2017).  I get the exact same results in PhpStorm too.  In Eclipse, I go to Project -> Properties -> Source Paths -> Include Path -> Libraries tab -> Add External PHARS... and point the filechooser to where phpunit.phar lives.  Is there another setting where I need to configure this?  I'm using php 7.1.10.   Yes, I'm using composer as well.  Thanks!

Comment: use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase as BaseTestCase;

abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase {} throws cannot be resolved to a type errors... which is odd because Eclipse will autocomplete the use and extends statements.  Really confused here.  Yes, I'm new to php.

Comment: Install phpunit with composer as I suggested above. To run test you need to simply execute `/your/project/path/vendor/bin/phpunit` the same path you can add to your settings if you want to be fully integrated with IDE

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I did that.  I'm editing the original post so you can see screenshots.